# If $a^2b=ba^2$ and $ab^2=b^2a$, does it follow that $ab=ba$?

Tags: group-theory, matrices

a,b are elements of the group G

I have no idea how to even start - I was thinking of defining a,b as two square matrices and using the non-commutative property of matrix multiplication but I'm not sure if that's the way to go...

Comment: What are $a$ and $b$?

Comment: Perhaps the tag group-theory implies these matrices need to be invertible.

Comment: Sorry a,b are elements of a group G

Comment: I don't know if I'm even supposed to use matrices - that's just the first thing I thought of.

Comment: Manasa, the answers below were based on assuming $a$ and $b$ are just matrices before your comment added context.  The answer is still no, and you could still show it using 2-by-2 matrices, but invertible ones instead: try it!  (Try to choose $a$ and $b$ so that their squares commute with everything, even though they don't commute with each other.)

Comment: It certainly implies $a^2b^2=b^2a^2$.

Comment: There is also a counterexample in a group with $6$ elements.

Comment: @JonasMeyer, do the matrices have to be invertible due to the inverse property of groups?

Comment: @Manasa: If you're looking for a counterexample with matrices, then they do have to be invertible. In the future, please specify what $a,b$ actually are.

Comment: Why do they have to be invertible?

Comment: @Manasa: I'm assuming that you want the group operation to be matrix multiplication. In that case, every element needs a multiplicative inverse because that's part of the definition of a group.

Comment: Matrix multiplication just happened to be the first thing I thought of but I don't know if that's actually how I'm supposed to approach it. And thanks for clarifying, I thought that might be the reason.

Answer (score 5):

Since you want this to be in a group, take the group of permutations of $\{1,2,3\}$ and take the counterexample $a$ and $b$ to be two distinct transpositions, say $(1,2)$ and $(2,3)$.

Comment: Could you possibly expand on that? I'm not quite sure what you mean.

Comment: @Manasa: $(1\;2)(1\;2)$ and $(2\;3)(2\;3)$ are the identity, but $(1\;2)$ and $(2\;3)$ do not commute.

Comment: I'm probably not thinking about this properly but how are they the identity? Are you multiplying them together?

Comment: @Manasa: Are you familiar with [cycle notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_notation)?

Comment: @wj32 No, it hasn't been covered yet but I'll have a look at your link.

Answer (score 4):

Consider the multiplicative subgroup of the [quaternions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion) consisting of $\pm 1$, $\pm i$, $\pm j$, and $\pm k$. Let $a=i$ and $b=j$. We have $ij^2=-i$ and $j^2i=-i$ but $ij\ne ji$.